# Running a simple test on cypress-ct

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use cypress-ct to test react components.  I have the following code in App.js

```
import {mount} from '@cypress/react'
import App from './App'

it('works', () => {
 mount(<App />)
})
```

But when I run cypress-ct and open the test file I get a "No tests found." message.  I've also tried with expect(true).to.be(true) and get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

why would you put these code in your `App.js`?
The code should be put in the right folder with the name `App.test.js` (or `App.spec.js`).
That's when the test would be found.
Hope this is helpful.

[component routes need to be specify in the config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrRmP.png)